# I am trying to get an average word count from a txt file. using python

Tags: python

```py
file=open("apple.txt","r")
letters=0
for line in file:
    words=line.split()
    for character in words:
        if character<=90 and character>=65:            #ascii code for the uppercase letters
            letters=letters+=1
        elif character<=122 and character>=97:         #ascii code for lowercase letters
            letters=letters+=1
```

This is what I have so far and the problems I am having right now is that there is a syntax error for the letters+=1 that I am not understanding and It says that I cant do the sixth line because it mentions you can't do a "str" and "int". These are my problems so far. The reason for the character stuff is because im trying to get exclude everything except uppercase and lowercase letters.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please make sure to format your code properly when asking questions

Comment: Note that iterating over a string (as you're doing) will yield strings containing the individual characters, which can't be compared to numbers like you're trying to do. Compare to strings or convert the characters to their codes using `ord()`.

Answer (score 2):

Careful with your operators. I see you're doing `letters=letters+=1`. You're mixing two things. You can increment using either `letter += 1` or `letter = letter+1`

Comment: Thanks for spotting that. But it still gives me a syntax error. Also if anyone knows how to fix the sixth line about my the program not being able to do "int" and "str" it would be much appreciated. I don't know what or how I should turn my character variable into.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're trying to compare an integer to a string. You'd have to change the type of the character variable to int

```
if int(character)<=90 and int(character)>=65:                      
    letters+=1
elif int(character)<=122 and int(character)>=97:         
    letters+=1
```

Comment: Hey, instead of ```int(character)``` everytime you use ```character```, just define at the start of the loop: ```character = int(character)```.

Comment: you want `ord()` not `int()`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do exactly, but here a few errors with your code.
First:

```py
letters = letters += 1
```

So, the problem here is that you can do:

```py
letters += 1
```

or

```py
letters = letters + 1
```

You are confusing the two, giving a syntax error.

Nextly:

```py
if character<=90 and character>=65:
```

and

```py
elif character<=122 and character>=97:
```

I'm guessing `character` is a string, you can check this by doing `type(character)`:
Now here, you are trying to compare the string `character` to a number, and you can't do that in python. If `character` is just a number contained in a string, then you can do `int(character)` and then compare them. Here is the new code:

```py
file=open("apple.txt","r")
letters=0
for line in file:
    words=line.split()
    for character in words:
        character = int(character)
        if character<=90 and character>=65:            #ascii code for the uppercase letters
            letters+=1
        elif character<=122 and character>=97:         #ascii code for lowercase letters
            letters+=1
```

I hope this solves your problem :)

Comment: I appreciate the help but now it gives me this error   character = int(character)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'I' which im not too sure what it means

Comment: you want `ord()` not `int()` there

Comment: Oh, I didn't realise that sorry

Comment: So, this means that character is something like "10s" which will throw an error when ```int(character) ``` is done, I specified this, however as @kindall said, you can use ```ord()```